# Converting DataFrame column into array using group by key

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am working on spark dataframes and I need to do a group by of a column employee , designation and company and convert the column values of grouped rows into an array of elements as new column. Example :

```
Input:

employee | Company Address | designation | company | Home Adress
--------------------------------------------------
Micheal  |  NY     | Head        | xyz     | YN
Micheal  |  NJ     | Head        | xyz     | YM

Output:

employee | designation | company | Address
--------------------------------------------------
Micheal  | Head        | xyz     | [Company Address : NY , Home Adress YN], [Company Address : NJ , Home Adress : Ym]
```

Any help is highly appreciated.!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below solution in spark for array instead of json,

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

df1 = sc.parallelize([['Micheal','NY','head','XYZ','YN'], ['Micheal','NJ','head','XYZ','YM']]).toDF(("Employee", "Company Address", "designation", "company","Home Adress"))

df2 = df1.groupBy("Employee", "designation", "company").agg(collect_list(struct(col("Company Address"),col("Home Adress"))).alias("Address"))

df2.show(1,False)
```

Output:

```
+--------+-----------+-------+--------------------+
|Employee|designation|company|Address             |
+--------+-----------+-------+--------------------+
|Micheal |head       |XYZ    |[[NY, YN], [NJ, YM]]|
+--------+-----------+-------+--------------------+
```

Comment: @ Ajay_SK will it contain duplicate ?

Comment: and how will I extract value of  company address for each row

Comment: Don't go with my df2.show(1, False), if you try df2.show() you will see only unique record.

Comment: If you want to get company address from data frame, select address field first, which is list of addresses. And from each  address list you can extract company address which is always on first index position.

Comment: @ Ajay_SK Like I need duplicate records so basically It will contain duplicate ??

Comment: can u write code I am new to scala and please consider the name of column rather than index

Comment: and Is the above collect_list valid for spark ?

Comment: sorry for confusion this code is pyspark, need to rewrite using scala